# Creating functions in TCL

Tags: tcl

Can any one help me in TCL programming, I am new to TCL
I would like to create functions like

```
employee_data Name() Dept() Tasks() ...
```

suppose i need execute from above function like  `employee_data Name() Tasks() ...`
here i want skip `Dept()`  arguments,

I tried to create function like but it does not work out..

```
proc employee_data {
    Name  (A B C....)
    Dept  (a b c....)
    Tasks (s  d f...) 

} employee_data; 

proc employee_data { Name($A $B $C) Dept($a $b $b) Tasks ($s  $d $f) } {

    Body...

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know any other programming language? It'll be easier for me to explain tcl in terms of that language since you have lots of confusing misconceptions that you seem to be inheriting from other languages.

Comment: Thanks for reply i knew C, C++

Answer (score 2):

Just so as you know, Tcl and C++ have very different approaches to values and types. In particular, Tcl works almost entirely by logically-immutable references to values that are nevertheless type-mutable, which is *very* different to C++ (and many other languages, to be fair). True mutator operations (such as increments) actually create copies.

Another key difference is that in Tcl, everything is done by executing commands. That includes creating other commands. That `proc`? It's a call to a command (called `proc`) which immediately creates a procedure with the given name, arguments and body. There's nothing like declaration; stuff happens when you tell the code to make it happen. This sounds rather more complicated than it is.

### How to pass list values into procedures

Suppose your `Name` was a list, you'd then pass the whole list value in (by immutable reference, so fast and safe) and the code inside could do whatever it wants without affecting the outside world. You'd then write that like this:

```
# Define
proc employee_data {Name ...} {
    lassign $Name A B C
    # ... do other processing ...
}

# Call
set Name {Aitem Bitem Citem}
employee_data $Name ...
```

You could also call with immediately-defined data; Tcl's entirely happy with this:

```
employee_data {Aitem Bitem Citem} ...
```

### Passing in dictionary values

Dictionaries are very much like lists, except they map keys to values instead of being sequences.

```
proc employee_data {Name ...} {
    dict with Name {}
    # ...
}

set Name {A "foo" B "bar" C "grill"}
employee_data $Name ...
```

You can also pass a *copy* of the *contents* of an (associative) array as a dictionary value, like this:

```
employee_data [dict get Name] ...
```

### Passing references

But suppose you wanted to mutate the outside world! To do that, you have to pass the *name of the variable* to change. You then use `upvar` to bind a local variable to the caller's variable so that you can do the modifications and have them stick. The `upvar` command lets you do in effect call-by-name, and it's highly magical.

```
proc employee_data {NameVar ...} {
    upvar $NameVar name
    # ... accessing $name as if it was whatever variable was passed ...
}

set Name {Aitem Bitem Citem}
# Note: *not* $Name! We want the name, not the contents!
employee_data Name ...
```

You can think of built-in commands like `set` and `incr` as working like this. And this works for associative arrays too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the basic misunderstanding is how you call/invoke Tcl functions/commands.

Unlike many other languages, where you invoke a function with `func(arg1,arg2,"arg3",arg4)` Tcl uses `func $arg1 $arg2 "arg3" $arg4`, where `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg4` are variables.

To define such a function, use `proc`. The syntax is

```
proc sum {a b} {
    return [expr {$a + $b}]
}
```

`a b` is the arguments list. Note that you don't need to declare the function.

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do here, but it looks more or less like a struct/class for me.

Comment: I am trying to create function with some optional arguments  proc sum {a(1 2 3) b(4 5 6) c(1 3 2)} {  Body ...ex: i need execute command like sum a(1 2 3) c(0 0 4) or sum a(1 2 3) b(0 0 4)